# Measuring memory pressure/GC execution in C#

Tags: c#, memory, garbage-collection

Is there any way I can measure the memory pressure caused by a program, and how many times the GC is being executed in background?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, by using the [.Net performance counters](https://web.archive.org/web/20141216094650/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x2tyfybc.aspx).

For programmatic access to those, see [msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/356cx381.aspx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/356cx381.aspx).